# How to add multiple hosts in InternetAddress.lookup?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am trying to add another host like bing.com and listen to both of them, but the code is wrong. How can I achieve it?

Here is my wrong code:

```
try {
      final List<InternetAddress> result =
      await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com' && 'bing.com');
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        isConnected = true;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Future<bool> _checkInternetAccess() {
    /// We use a mix of IPV4 and IPV6 here in case some networks only accept one of the types.
    /// Only tested with an IPV4 only network so far (I don't have access to an IPV6 network).
    final List<InternetAddress> dnss = [
      InternetAddress('8.8.8.8', type: InternetAddressType.IPv4), // Google
      InternetAddress('2001:4860:4860::8888', type: InternetAddressType.IPv6), // Google
      InternetAddress('1.1.1.1', type: InternetAddressType.IPv4), // CloudFlare
      InternetAddress('2606:4700:4700::1111', type: InternetAddressType.IPv6), // CloudFlare
      InternetAddress('208.67.222.222', type: InternetAddressType.IPv4), // OpenDNS
      InternetAddress('2620:0:ccc::2', type: InternetAddressType.IPv6), // OpenDNS
      InternetAddress('180.76.76.76', type: InternetAddressType.IPv4), // Baidu
      InternetAddress('2400:da00::6666', type: InternetAddressType.IPv6), // Baidu
    ];

    final Completer<bool> completer = Completer<bool>();

    int callsReturned = 0;
    void onCallReturned(bool isAlive) {
      if (completer.isCompleted) return;

      if (isAlive) {
        completer.complete(true);
      } else {
        callsReturned++;
        if (callsReturned >= dnss.length) {
          completer.complete(false);
        }
      }
    }

    dnss.forEach((dns) => _pingDns(dns).then(onCallReturned));

    return completer.future;
  }

  Future<bool> _pingDns(InternetAddress dnsAddress) async {
    const int dnsPort = 53;
    const Duration timeout = Duration(seconds: 3);

    Socket socket;
    try {
      socket = await Socket.connect(dnsAddress, dnsPort, timeout: timeout);
      socket?.destroy();
      return true;
    } on SocketException {
      socket?.destroy();
    }
    return false;
  }
```